# Postfix SMTP message being marked as SPAM by Gmail and Yahoo

Tags: email, gmail, smtp, postfix

I'm having a problem getting my low-volume of legitimate email messages through the SPAM filters of Gmail and Yahoo.

I have followed Gmail's guide here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126

I have also confirmed with [mail-tester](http://mail-tester.com) that my SPF, DKIM, etc are configured properly.  Additional testing with MXToolbox confirms.

**Header of message marked as SPAM:**

```
Delivered-To: jimmyjammypantz@gmail.com
Received: by 10.112.56.241 with SMTP id d17csp86403lbq;
    Thu, 6 Nov 2014 11:15:17 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.224.74.194 with SMTP id v2mr357017qaj.60.1415301316654;
    Thu, 06 Nov 2014 11:15:16 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <test@ruestow.me>
Received: from otto.ruestow.me (otto.ruestow.me. [104.200.30.156])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id i51si753158qge.66.2014.11.06.11.15.15
    for <jimmyjammypantz@gmail.com>;
    Thu, 06 Nov 2014 11:15:16 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of test@ruestow.me designates 104.200.30.156 as permitted sender) client-ip=104.200.30.156;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of test@ruestow.me designates 104.200.30.156 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=test@ruestow.me;
   dkim=pass (test mode) header.i=@ruestow.me
Received: from unknown (7.sub-70-195-135.myvzw.com [70.195.135.7])
by otto.ruestow.me (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 489E310EBF;
Thu,  6 Nov 2014 19:15:15 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=ruestow.me; s=mail;
t=1415301315; bh=SYpysskAyXNoTxgk6KAYV1J+Y66Vdru6zanrsAPM7xQ=;
h=Date:From:To:Subject;
b=W/In0Q7EyxGtHeDW4eMQfIcqkzRiiysVhpTi2Mzp627ctZ7hHPVOzk17ZlKYM+goc
 XFpCZJDGCMNKL8jLSnJ+c1AwE8F9rELE9UR3Q/6fUReo01p/JCAnKxRI3jRkT8dDfC
 7fqanP1qQlLU2ac4NBfrk4oEKMDyz4GreuxCYCW8=
Date: Thu, 6 Nov 2014 14:15:13 -0500
From: test <test@ruestow.me>
To: jimmyjammypantz@yahoo.com, jimmyjammypantz@gmail.com
Subject: hello old friend
Message-ID: <20141106141513.000075c0@unknown>
X-Mailer: Claws Mail 3.9.1 (GTK+ 2.24.24; i686-w64-mingw32)
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

#Enabling SMTP for authenticated users, and handing off authentication to Dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = otto.ruestow.me
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

#Handing off local delivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store mail
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

#Virtual domains, users, and aliases
#virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = ruestow.me, otto.ruestow.me, localhost.ruestow.me, localhost
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891,inet:localhost:8892
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891,inet:localhost:8892
```

I suspect that the header entry:

```
Received: from unknown (7.sub-70-195-135.myvzw.com [70.195.135.7])
by otto.ruestow.me (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 489E310EBF;
Thu,  6 Nov 2014 19:15:15 +0000 (UTC)
```

might be the problem.  What should I troubleshoot next to allow my messages to be delivered properly?

** UPDATE **
I've reconfigured my mail client to send the email address in the Message-ID, and to set the domain in the 'Received: from' header entry, but these messages are still marked as SPAM.  I'm stumped.

```
Received: from ruestow.me (7.sub-70-195-135.myvzw.com [70.195.135.7])
by otto.ruestow.me (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id D97CF10ED7
for <jimmyjammypantz@gmail.com>; Thu,  6 Nov 2014 20:41:11 +0000 (UTC)

Message-ID: <20141106154109.0000789a.test@ruestow.me>
```

Comment: my rDNS is also configured properly...

    `IP: 104.200.30.156
    HELO: otto.ruestow.me
    rDNS: otto.ruestow.me`

Comment: Your email has no Subject header.

Comment: Sorry I missed the last few lines of the header, I've updated the post to include the full header.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is really relevant to you anymore but I will post this anyway for anyone else that finds this post.

The only real solution would be to either use a certificate signed by a CA that Google trusts or find a SMTP relay.

In some cases you can use your ISP's SMTP server as a relay.